# Error when installing libv8 3.11.8.3

Tags: ruby, macos, gcc, libv8, osx-mavericks

I'm running fresh install of OSX 10.9 Mavericks and XCode 5.0.1. When i'm trying to run bundle install in my project it fails on installing libv8 gem. Here's the output:

```
ERROR:  Error installing libv8:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby extconf.rb
    creating Makefile
    Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
    Unable to find a compiler officially supported by v8.
    It is recommended to use GCC v4.4 or higher
    Using compiler: g++
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/atomicops_internals_x86_gcc.o has no symbols
    In file included from ../src/accessors.cc:28:
    In file included from ../src/v8.h:60:
    In file included from ../src/objects-inl.h:38:
    In file included from ../src/elements.h:33:
    In file included from ../src/heap.h:41:
    ../src/store-buffer.h:229:9: error: private field 'heap_' is not used [-Werror,-Wunused-private-field]
      Heap* heap_;
            ^
    1 error generated.
    make[1]: *** [/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/v8_base/src/accessors.o] Error 1
    make: *** [x64.release] Error 2
    GYP_GENERATORS=make \
        build/gyp/gyp --generator-output="out" build/all.gyp \
                      -Ibuild/standalone.gypi --depth=. \
                      -Dv8_target_arch=x64 \
                      -S.x64 -Dhost_arch=x64
      CXX(target) /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/allocation.o
      CXX(target) /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/atomicops_internals_x86_gcc.o
      CXX(target) /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/bignum.o
      CXX(target) /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/bignum-dtoa.o
      CXX(target) /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/cached-powers.o
      CXX(target) /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/conversions.o
      CXX(target) /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/diy-fp.o
      CXX(target) /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/dtoa.o
      CXX(target) /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/fast-dtoa.o
      CXX(target) /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/fixed-dtoa.o
      CXX(target) /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/once.o
      CXX(target) /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/preparse-data.o
      CXX(target) /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/preparser.o
      CXX(target) /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/preparser-api.o
      CXX(target) /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/scanner.o
      CXX(target) /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/strtod.o
      CXX(target) /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/token.o
      CXX(target) /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/unicode.o
      CXX(target) /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/utils.o
      LIBTOOL-STATIC /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/libpreparser_lib.a
      CXX(target) /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser/preparser/preparser-process.o
      LINK(target) /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/preparser
      CXX(target) /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/v8_base/src/accessors.o


    Gem files will remain installed in /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3 for inspection.
    Results logged to /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3/ext/libv8/gem_make.out
```

Also when doing

```
gcc -v
```

i'm getting

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

I've tried installing gcc via homebrew, but this doesn't help. What are other possible solutions?

Answer (score 6):

Switch to an older version of Xcode didn't work for me. Instead I used last libv8 fixes from github : https://github.com/cowboyd/libv8/issues/107

It works perfectly.

Comment: Followed the steps in the comments to compile/install locally and it worked for me.

Comment: This is what finally worked after much SO crawling. For others who've been having OSX10.9 problems, I also installed Mavericks XCODE 5.1 Command Line tools manually - it used to be such you could install it from within xcode, but now I believe you need to go to the "Downloads for apple developers" site https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=for%20Xcode%20-# and using your apple id (no dev account needed) download command line tools under the 10.9 tab.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, installing older version of Xcode (4.6.3) and changing Command Line Tools version to the older ones in Xcode's preferences solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Install XCode 4.6.3 in your Applications folder, and then run

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode4.6.3.app/Contents/Developer
```

Once you're done installing libv8 you can revert back by doing

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```