# How to fix libv8 error from Gemfile on Mavericks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundle, osx-mavericks

When I run `bundle install` I get

```
An error occurred while installing libv8 (3.11.8.17), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install libv8 -v '3.11.8.17'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Libv8 is dependency for `lunchy` and `therubyracer` gems.

I have locked in my `Gemfile.lock` libv8 gem on `3.11.8.17`

But I found that I can downgrade it to `3.3.10.4`

[bundle install / update: libv8 (therubyracer) installation fails (with native extensions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126465/bundle-install-update-libv8-therubyracer-installation-fails-with-native-ex)

How to do that?

I also found working `3.11.8.17` gem but don't know how to implement it on my system.
https://github.com/cowboyd/libv8/issues/107#issuecomment-26146673

Comment: Can you update `libv8` to `3.16.14.3` and `therubyracer` to `0.12.0`? I've seen similar issue today and bumping those gems fixed it.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can actually install that version on Mavericks:

```
gem install libv8 -v 3.11.8.17 -- --with-system-v8
```

I can confirm this works with rbenv and ruby 1.9.3p448

See a similar thread here [Installing libv8 gem on OS X 10.9+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19577759/installing-libv8-gem-on-mavericks)

Comment: worked like a charm for me.  what's the long term implication of using this over homebrew? Is it going to be more difficult to maintain?

Comment: Hi Nikola. Homebrew packages are getting there with Mavericks. However there are some things you can do to set up for success with your gem compilations etc. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19668162/2012130

Answer (score 14):

You need to reinstall libv8

```
$ gem uninstall libv8
$ brew install v8
$ gem install therubyracer
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with

gem "therubyracer", "~> 0.10.2" to Gemfile

And it will install dependent gem libv8 (3.3.10.4) and the issue of build gem native extension failure got resolve.

Answer (score 0):

try upgrading your ruby to the highest patch level.  libv8 and the rubyracer gem installed right away after I upgraded ruby-1.8.7 after going from p357 to p375.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below commands, this will solve the problem for sure:

gem install rmagick -v '2.13.2'

and then do: 
gem install libv8 -v 3.11.8.17 -- --with-system-v8