# gem install debugger -v '1.5.0' fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, bundler, rbenv

I am trying to do `bundle` in the large project on Mavericks and some gems are broken or something wrong with my environment in spite of this is fresh install of rbenv.

```
$ gem install debugger -v '1.5.0'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing debugger:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/samat/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for rb_method_entry_t.called_id in method.h... no
checking for rb_control_frame_t.method_id in method.h... no
checking for rb_method_entry_t.called_id in method.h... no
checking for rb_control_frame_t.method_id in method.h... no
Makefile creation failed
**************************************************************************
No source for ruby-1.9.3-p448 provided with debugger-ruby_core_source gem.
**************************************************************************
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
    ...
```

Have no idea of what configuration options do I need

In mkmf I see things like

```
"gcc -I/Users/samat/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin13.0.0 -I/Users/samat/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/Users/samat/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -I/Users/samat/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby-1.9.3-p448 -I'/Users/samat/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/include'  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE  -I'/Users/samat/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/include'   -O3 -Wno-error=shorten-64-to-32  -pipe   -c conftest.c"
conftest.c:3:10: fatal error: 'method.h' file not found
#include <method.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <method.h>
    ...
```

I use rbenv,

```
$ rbenv version
1.9.3-p448 (set by /Users/samat/Documents/bm-git/.ruby-version)
```

Comment: It looks like your machine is missing some c/c++ libraries.  Do you have libc and libc-devel etc installed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You better to use latest version of debugger, bc [issue](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger/issues/87) with your Ruby version was solved.

Answer (score 12):

From the [debugger page](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger) it says that if the ruby source can't be found, it will try to install debugger-ruby_core_source, which is actually what fails for me.  I use rbenv, so I according to the debugger gem instructions, I pointed it to the rbenv source.

`gem install debugger -- --with-ruby-include=~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484/include`

Comment: The accepted answer didn't work for me, but this did and saved me a day and is really a more useful solution. It's worth noting that the path to the include would vary and brew users might find it somewhere like: /usr/local/var/rbenv/... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of issues with Ruby gems and Mavericks. What I have found is that the best bet is to use the apple-gcc42 compiler from [homebrew](http://brew.sh/)

```
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew install apple-gcc42
```

Then force that compiler family to be used when building gems. I put symlinks in my a bin folder in my home directory

```
cd $HOME/bin
ln -s /usr/local/bin/c++-4.2 c++
ln -s /usr/local/bin/g++-4.2 g++
ln -s /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2 cc
ln -s /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2 gcc
```

You'll need to have your local bin folder on your path.

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Then you should be good to go.

Comment: After hours of trying to get libv8 and therubyracer installed on Mavericks, _this_ was the solution (aside from $HOME not being set, but that was trivial). Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad it helped James!

Answer (score 0):

may be this will help you `gem install debugger-linecache -v '1.1.2' -- --with-ruby-include=$rvm_path/src/ruby-1.9.3-p286/`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this issue is related with missing package.  Most of the time these files (for instance `method.h`) belongs to package named `libXXX-dev`.

It's difficult for us to know what the package contains file.  I've recently bumped into a utility to deal with this annoying problem (for those who works with `apt-get` package manager).  The tool is `apt-file` and you can use it as follow:

1. Installation: `sudo apt-get install apt-file`
2. Updating apt-file db: `sudo apt-file update`
3. Looking at file: `sudo apt-file search 'method.h'`

The result might be:

```
...
libcxxtools-dev: /usr/include/cxxtools/constmethod.h
libcxxtools-dev: /usr/include/cxxtools/method.h
libcxxtools-dev: /usr/include/cxxtools/unit/testmethod.h
libgcj12-dev: /usr/include/c++/4.6/gcj/method.h
libgcj13-dev: /usr/include/c++/4.7/gcj/method.h
...
```

In the particular case of `debugger`gem the missing package is `libcxxtools-dev``

I'm on Debian 3.2.54-2 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

For me it was an issue of permission.

I was able to solve this issue with

> **sudo** gem install debugger

If this doesn't help you may have to get involved in a dependency rabbit hole.