# Fix therubyracer/libv8 (0.12.1) installation on Mavericks

Tags: gcc, rubygems, v8, therubyracer, libv8

OK, I’m at the end of my tether with this. There are a few similar questions but they all refer to therubyracer 0.10, and they mostly conclude that the problem can be fixed by upgrading to 0.12.

I’m having similar problems, but when I use 0.12.

#### Similar questions

- [Installing libv8 gem on Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19577759/installing-libv8-gem-on-mavericks)
- [How to fix libv8 error from Gemfile on Mavericks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568852/how-to-fix-libv8-error-from-gemfile-on-mavericks)

I’m having problems using ‘standard’ (xcode?) gcc, and both apple-gcc42 and gcc from homebrew. I’ve tried both `--with-system-v8` and `--without-system-v8`, and again, no dice.

Here’s some logs:

### Starting from scratch…

```
 $ cd ~/Documents/code/website
 $ rvm gemset empty
 $ ruby -v
 ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
 $ grep rubyracer Gemfile
 gem 'therubyracer', '~> 0.12.0'
 $ brew list | grep v8
 $ cat ~/.bundle/config 
 $ cat .bundle/config 
 BUNDLE_BIN: bin
 $ $CXX
 $ $CPP
 $ $CC
 $ which gcc
 /usr/bin/gcc
 $ which g++
 /usr/bin/g++
 $ g++ -v
 Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with- 
 gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
 Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
 Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
 Thread model: posix
```

### Try a bundle install

```
Installing libv8 (3.16.14.3) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/chris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
creating Makefile
Compiling v8 for x64
Using python 2.7.5
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Unable to find a compiler officially supported by v8.
It is recommended to use GCC v4.4 or higher
Using compiler: g++
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Unable to find a compiler officially supported by v8.
It is recommended to use GCC v4.4 or higher
../src/cached-powers.cc:136:18: error: unused variable 'kCachedPowersLength' [-Werror,-Wunused-const-variable]
static const int kCachedPowersLength = ARRAY_SIZE(kCachedPowers);
                 ^
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [/Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@website/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/cached-powers.o] Error 1
make: *** [x64.release] Error 2
/Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@website/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/location.rb:36:in `block in verify_installation!': libv8 did not install properly, expected binary v8 archive '/Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@website/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_base.a'to exist, but it was not found (Libv8::Location::Vendor::ArchiveNotFound)
    from /Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@website/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/location.rb:35:in `each'
    from /Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@website/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/location.rb:35:in `verify_installation!'
    from /Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@website/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/location.rb:26:in `install!'
    from extconf.rb:7:in `<main>'
GYP_GENERATORS=make \
    build/gyp/gyp --generator-output="out" build/all.gyp \
                  -Ibuild/standalone.gypi --depth=. \
                  -Dv8_target_arch=x64 \
                  -S.x64  -Dv8_enable_backtrace=1 -Dv8_can_use_vfp2_instructions=true -Darm_fpu=vfpv2 -Dv8_can_use_vfp3_instructions=true -Darm_fpu=vfpv3
  CXX(target) /Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@website/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/allocation.o
  CXX(target) /Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@website/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/atomicops_internals_x86_gcc.o
  CXX(target) /Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@website/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/bignum.o
  CXX(target) /Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@website/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/bignum-dtoa.o
  CXX(target) /Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@website/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/cached-powers.o


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@website/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@website/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing libv8 (3.16.14.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
```

### Bad times.

Error message advises that gcc 4.4+ is recommended. We can do that.

```
$ export CXX=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.2/bin/g++-4.8 
$ export CPP=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.2/bin/cpp-4.8 
$ export CC=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.2/bin/gcc-4.8 
$ which $CXX
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.2/bin/g++-4.8
$ which $CPP
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.2/bin/cpp-4.8
$ which $CC
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.2/bin/gcc-4.8
$ bundle install
…
Installing libv8 (3.16.14.3) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/chris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
creating Makefile
Compiling v8 for x64
Using python 2.7.5
Using compiler: /usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.2/bin/g++-4.8
g++-4.8: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wnewline-eof'
make[1]: *** [/Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@website/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/allocation.o] Error 1
make: *** [x64.release] Error 2
/Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@website/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/location.rb:36:in `block in verify_installation!': libv8 did not install properly, expected binary v8 archive '/Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@website/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_base.a'to exist, but it was not found (Libv8::Location::Vendor::ArchiveNotFound)
    from /Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@website/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/location.rb:35:in `each'
    from /Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@website/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/location.rb:35:in `verify_installation!'
    from /Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@website/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/location.rb:26:in `install!'
    from extconf.rb:7:in `<main>'
GYP_GENERATORS=make \
    build/gyp/gyp --generator-output="out" build/all.gyp \
                  -Ibuild/standalone.gypi --depth=. \
                  -Dv8_target_arch=x64 \
                  -S.x64  -Dv8_enable_backtrace=1 -Dv8_can_use_vfp2_instructions=true -Darm_fpu=vfpv2 -Dv8_can_use_vfp3_instructions=true -Darm_fpu=vfpv3
  CXX(target) /Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@website/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/allocation.o


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@website/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@website/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing libv8 (3.16.14.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

### Worse times!

OK. So to fix the issues with therubyracer 0.10, some people recommend brew installing v8, then telling rubygems to use system v8. Let’s see what happens!

```
$ brew install v8
==> Downloading https://github.com/v8/v8/archive/3.21.17.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/v8-3.21.17.tar.gz
==> Checking out http://gyp.googlecode.com/svn/trunk
==> make native -j4 library=shared snapshot=on console=readline i18nsupport=off
  /usr/local/Cellar/v8/3.21.17: 21 files, 27M, built in 3.4 minutes
$ cat ~/.bundle/config 
---
BUNDLE_BUILD__LIBV8: --with-system-v8
$ bundle install
…
Installing therubyracer (0.12.1) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/chris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for main() in -lpthread... yes
checking for main() in -lobjc... yes
checking for v8.h... yes
creating Makefile

make
compiling accessor.cc
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
In file included from accessor.cc:1:
./rr.h:463:14: error: no type named 'AccessorGetter' in namespace 'v8'
  inline v8::AccessorGetter accessorGetter() {return &AccessorGetter;}
         ~~~~^
./rr.h:464:14: error: no type named 'AccessorSetter' in namespace 'v8'
  inline v8::AccessorSetter accessorSetter() {return RTEST(set) ? &AccessorSetter : 0;}
         ~~~~^
./rr.h:466:14: error: no type named 'NamedPropertyGetter' in namespace 'v8'
  inline v8::NamedPropertyGetter namedPropertyGetter() {return &NamedPropertyGetter;}
         ~~~~^
./rr.h:467:14: error: no type named 'NamedPropertySetter' in namespace 'v8'
  inline v8::NamedPropertySetter namedPropertySetter() {return RTEST(set) ? &NamedPropertySetter : 0;}
         ~~~~^
./rr.h:468:14: error: no type named 'NamedPropertyQuery' in namespace 'v8'
  inline v8::NamedPropertyQuery namedPropertyQuery() {return RTEST(query) ? &NamedPropertyQuery : 0;}
         ~~~~^
./rr.h:469:14: error: no type named 'NamedPropertyDeleter' in namespace 'v8'
  inline v8::NamedPropertyDeleter namedPropertyDeleter() {return RTEST(deleter) ? &NamedPropertyDeleter : 0;}
         ~~~~^
./rr.h:470:14: error: no type named 'NamedPropertyEnumerator' in namespace 'v8'
  inline v8::NamedPropertyEnumerator namedPropertyEnumerator() {return RTEST(enumerator) ? &NamedPropertyEnumerator : 0;}
         ~~~~^
./rr.h:472:14: error: no type named 'IndexedPropertyGetter' in namespace 'v8'
  inline v8::IndexedPropertyGetter indexedPropertyGetter() {return &IndexedPropertyGetter;}
         ~~~~^
./rr.h:473:14: error: no type named 'IndexedPropertySetter' in namespace 'v8'
  inline v8::IndexedPropertySetter indexedPropertySetter() {return RTEST(set) ? &IndexedPropertySetter : 0;}
         ~~~~^
./rr.h:474:14: error: no type named 'IndexedPropertyQuery' in namespace 'v8'
  inline v8::IndexedPropertyQuery indexedPropertyQuery() {return RTEST(query) ? &IndexedPropertyQuery : 0;}
         ~~~~^
./rr.h:475:14: error: no type named 'IndexedPropertyDeleter' in namespace 'v8'
  inline v8::IndexedPropertyDeleter indexedPropertyDeleter() {return RTEST(deleter) ? &IndexedPropertyDeleter : 0;}
         ~~~~^
./rr.h:476:14: error: no type named 'IndexedPropertyEnumerator' in namespace 'v8'
  inline v8::IndexedPropertyEnumerator indexedPropertyEnumerator() {return RTEST(enumerator) ? &IndexedPropertyEnumerator : 0;}
         ~~~~^
./rr.h:482:16: error: no type named 'AccessorInfo' in namespace 'v8'; did you mean 'Accessor'?
    Info(const v8::AccessorInfo& info);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
               Accessor
./rr.h:456:7: note: 'Accessor' declared here
class Accessor {
      ^
./rr.h:488:18: error: no type named 'AccessorInfo' in namespace 'v8'; did you mean 'Accessor'?
    inline const v8::AccessorInfo* operator->() {return this->info;}
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                 Accessor
./rr.h:456:7: note: 'Accessor' declared here
class Accessor {
      ^
./rr.h:502:11: error: no type named 'AccessorInfo' in namespace 'v8'; did you mean 'Accessor'?
    const v8::AccessorInfo* info;
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
          Accessor
./rr.h:456:7: note: 'Accessor' declared here
class Accessor {
      ^
./rr.h:506:85: error: no type named 'AccessorInfo' in namespace 'v8'; did you mean 'Accessor'?
  static v8::Handle<v8::Value> AccessorGetter(v8::Local<v8::String> property, const v8::AccessorInfo& info);
                                                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                                                    Accessor
./rr.h:456:7: note: 'Accessor' declared here
class Accessor {
      ^
./rr.h:507:96: error: no type named 'AccessorInfo' in namespace 'v8'; did you mean 'Accessor'?
  static void AccessorSetter(v8::Local<v8::String> property, v8::Local<v8::Value> value, const v8::AccessorInfo& info);
                                                                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                                                               Accessor
./rr.h:456:7: note: 'Accessor' declared here
class Accessor {
      ^
./rr.h:509:90: error: no type named 'AccessorInfo' in namespace 'v8'; did you mean 'Accessor'?
  static v8::Handle<v8::Value> NamedPropertyGetter(v8::Local<v8::String> property, const v8::AccessorInfo& info);
                                                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                                                         Accessor
./rr.h:456:7: note: 'Accessor' declared here
class Accessor {
      ^
./rr.h:510:118: error: no type named 'AccessorInfo' in namespace 'v8'; did you mean 'Accessor'?
  static v8::Handle<v8::Value> NamedPropertySetter(v8::Local<v8::String> property, v8::Local<v8::Value> value, const v8::AccessorInfo& info);
                                                                                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                                                                                     Accessor
./rr.h:456:7: note: 'Accessor' declared here
class Accessor {
      ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make: *** [accessor.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/ext/v8/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing therubyracer (0.12.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Completely scratching my head, and already wasted hours on this. If you can spot what’s going wrong and help me fix it, you’ll be my hero(ine) forever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so this is now sorted.

For future people with the same problem, I was suffering from having ruby built against a previous installation of OS X.

Fixed by completely nuking rvm and starting from scratch, though I imagine you could just uninstall/reinstall the offending ruby.

More details on how the problem was solved here:

https://github.com/cowboyd/libv8/issues/120

Answer (score 46):

I was able to proceed with ruby racer after `rm Gemfile.lock`  Perhaps try this, which is easier than the RVM nuke option.

beforehand:
I installed v8 via `brew install v8`, and then did `gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3' -- --with-system-v8`

and I am running 10.10 Yosemite

Comment: I had to `brew install v8` then `bundle config build.libv8 -- --with-system-v8` and then `bundle install`

Comment: nooo, removing Gemfile.lock implies an update of all gems. If you do this, be ready to test heavily.

Answer (score 17):

I was able to get things going again by running `gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3' -- --with-system-v8`.

Reference: https://github.com/cowboyd/libv8/issues/120

Comment: FYI... that did resolve part of the problem for me, but I was left with 'error: no member named 'ScriptData' in namespace 'v8'' errors. Continuing my search.

Comment: Sounds not fun ;). Good luck!

Comment: Definitely; finally just removed therubyracer and now I'm able to move forward.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue with **OSX 10.9.3**, **ruby 2.1.3** and every version of **therubyracer**.

Now i'm letting **execjs** (uglifier gem dependencie) take care of it.

> ExecJS lets you run JavaScript code from Ruby. It automatically picks the best runtime available to evaluate your JavaScript program, then returns the result to you as a Ruby object.

#### OSX users

"Apple JavaScriptCore" comes as default for JS runtime on OSX. Just installing execjs will solve the problem.

#### Linux users

Install node.js. Execjs gem will automatically choose node.js as js runtime.

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

More information on github:

https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs

Answer (score 1):

It could be that `rubygems` is fetching the wrong binaries for your system.

Diagnosis:

- Compare the output of `gem env platform` to 'Kernel Version' under ` > About This Mac > System Report > Software`
- If those don't match (e.g. `Kernel Version: 14.4.0` and `x86_64-darwin-12`) then RubyGems is grabbing the wrong version of `therubyracer` and `libv8` for your system

Fix:

- short-term: `bundle update therubyracer --platform=x86_64-darwin-14`

Answer (score 0):

This issue no longer exists in the latest version of `therubyracer` (0.12.3).

```
bundle update therubyracer
```

Answer (score -1):

I had this same problem when I upgraded from OSX Mountain Lion to OSX Mavericks.
The patch level of ruby 1.8.7 apparently matters.

Upgrading from ruby-1.8.7-p354 to ruby-1.8.7-375 did the trick for me.

libv8 (3.16.14.3-x86_64-darwin-13) and the therubyracer (0.12.0) gems installed without problem.

assuming you use rbenv:

```
rbenv versions
  system
  * 1.8.7-p354
  2.0.0-rc2

rbenv uninstall 1.8.7-p354
rbenv install 1.8.7-p375

rbenv versions
  system
  * 1.8.7-p375
  2.0.0-rc2

bundle install
```