# Gem install therubyracer -v '0.11.4'?

Tags: therubyracer

I'm nearly crazy to install **therubyracer**. I know there're many people have the same problem with me, and I had also viewd these issues, however it's too complicated for me cause different situations have the different solutions. And in fact, there're have been not a good way to solve the problem. My problem is similar to [this](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer/issues/288), and there have a [discussion](https://github.com/cowboyd/libv8/pull/124) about it, however there're still have not a conclusion.

In spite of these, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481435/fix-therubyracer-libv8-0-12-1-installation-on-mavericks) is a good question asked by **Chris S**, but come not a good result.

① Here is some notes about my problem:

1.ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-darwin15]

2.libv8 3.11.8.17 with native extensions

② OS X El Capitan, 10.11

③ Here is the error messages:

```
ERROR:  Error installing therubyracer:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/hufeipeng/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20151026-41811-14t2l9a.rb extconf.rb

checking for main() in -lpthread... yes
checking for main() in -lobjc... yes
checking for v8.h... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling accessor.cc
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
In file included from accessor.cc:1:
In file included from ./rr.h:4:
/usr/local/include/v8.h:353:33: error: use of undeclared identifier 'nullptr'
V8_INLINE MaybeLocal() : val_(nullptr) {}
                            ^
/usr/local/include/v8.h:360:51: error: use of undeclared identifier 'nullptr'
V8_INLINE bool IsEmpty() const { return val_ == nullptr; }
                                              ^
/usr/local/include/v8.h:364:29: error: use of undeclared identifier 'nullptr'
out->val_ = IsEmpty() ? nullptr : this->val_;
                        ^
/usr/local/include/v8.h:430:50: error: use of undeclared identifier 'nullptr'
bool IsFirstPass() const { return callback_ != nullptr; }
                                             ^
/usr/local/include/v8.h:790:42: error: use of undeclared identifier 'nullptr'
V8_INLINE Global() : PersistentBase<T>(nullptr) {}
                                     ^
/usr/local/include/v8.h:815:18: error: use of undeclared identifier 'nullptr'
other.val_ = nullptr;
             ^
/usr/local/include/v8.h:827:18: error: use of undeclared identifier 'nullptr'
rhs.val_ = nullptr;
             ^
/usr/local/include/v8.h:1092:52: error: use of undeclared identifier 'nullptr'
ScriptOrigin* origin = nullptr));
                         ^
/usr/local/include/v8config.h:347:48: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATE_SOON'
#define V8_DEPRECATE_SOON(message, declarator) declarator
                                           ^
In file included from accessor.cc:1:
In file included from ./rr.h:4:
/usr/local/include/v8.h:1095:30: error: use of undeclared identifier 'nullptr'
ScriptOrigin* origin = nullptr);
                         ^
/usr/local/include/v8.h:2283:42: error: 'v8::NewStringType' is not a class, namespace, or scoped enumeration
kNormalString = static_cast<int>(v8::NewStringType::kNormal),
                                     ^
/usr/local/include/v8.h:2284:48: error: 'v8::NewStringType' is not a class, namespace, or scoped enumeration
kInternalizedString = static_cast<int>(v8::NewStringType::kInternalized)
                                           ^
/usr/local/include/v8.h:3205:36: error: use of undeclared identifier 'nullptr'
return NewInstance(context, 0, nullptr);
                               ^
/usr/local/include/v8.h:3434:38: error: 'v8::ArrayBufferCreationMode' is not a class, namespace, or scoped enumeration
ArrayBufferCreationMode mode = ArrayBufferCreationMode::kExternalized);
                                 ^
/usr/local/include/v8.h:3797:38: error: 'v8::ArrayBufferCreationMode' is not a class, namespace, or scoped enumeration
ArrayBufferCreationMode mode = ArrayBufferCreationMode::kExternalized);
                                 ^
/usr/local/include/v8.h:4457:36: error: 'v8::PropertyHandlerFlags' is not a class, namespace, or scoped enumeration
PropertyHandlerFlags flags = PropertyHandlerFlags::kNone)
                             ^
/usr/local/include/v8.h:4485:36: error: 'v8::PropertyHandlerFlags' is not a class, namespace, or scoped enumeration
PropertyHandlerFlags flags = PropertyHandlerFlags::kNone)
                             ^
/usr/local/include/v8.h:7151:27: error: use of undeclared identifier 'nullptr'
if (V8_UNLIKELY(val_ == nullptr)) V8::ToLocalEmpty();
                        ^
/usr/local/include/v8config.h:353:54: note: expanded from macro 'V8_UNLIKELY'
# define V8_UNLIKELY(condition) (__builtin_expect(!!(condition), 0))
                                                 ^
In file included from accessor.cc:1:
In file included from ./rr.h:4:
/usr/local/include/v8.h:7596:46: error: 'v8::NewStringType' is not a class, namespace, or scoped enumeration
Set(v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, name, NewStringType::kNormal)
                                         ^
In file included from accessor.cc:1:
./rr.h:358:39: error: no member named 'ScriptData' in namespace 'v8'
class ScriptData : public Pointer<v8::ScriptData> {
                              ~~~~^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make: *** [accessor.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in
/Users/*/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/therubyracer-0.11.4 for inspection.
Results logged to
/Users/*/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.2.0-static/therubyracer-0.11.4/gem_make.out
```

**Help!**

---

---

Well, firstly I'm so sorry to reedit the problem again, too busy no time to notice the comments your guys replied for me. And, here, I'm so appreciated that @Javid Jamae afford so great a way to me to solve the problem, although there're still some little matters to deal, but it's ok that we just need the errors to help us find the final answer. The follow is the console after I had try @Javid Jamae way,

First, I have not install **gcc** with **brew** before, so I installed it with brew and the version is the latest **5.2.0** (***/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/5.2.0***).  Here is the details:

```
➜  /Users/xxx  >brew install gcc
==> Installing dependencies for gcc: gmp, mpfr, libmpc, isl
==> Installing gcc dependency: gmp
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/gmp-6.0.0a.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring gmp-6.0.0a.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/gmp/6.0.0a: 15 files, 3.2M
==> Installing gcc dependency: mpfr
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/mpfr-3.1.3.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring mpfr-3.1.3.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/mpfr/3.1.3: 24 files, 3.6M
==> Installing gcc dependency: libmpc
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/libmpc-1.0.3.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring libmpc-1.0.3.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/libmpc/1.0.3: 10 files, 380K
==> Installing gcc dependency: isl
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/isl-0.14.1.el_capitan.bottle.3.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring isl-0.14.1.el_capitan.bottle.3.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/isl/0.14.1: 68 files, 3.2M
==> Installing gcc
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/gcc-5.2.0.el_capitan.bottle.2.tar.gz
##################### 29.8%
curl: (56) SSLRead() return error -9806
Error: Failed to download resource "gcc"
Download failed: https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/gcc-5.2.0.el_capitan.bottle.2.tar.gz
Warning: Bottle installation failed: building from source.
==> Downloading http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/gcc/gcc-5.2.0/gcc-5.2.0.tar.bz2
==> Downloading from http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/gnu/gcc/gcc-5.2.0/gcc-5.2.0.tar.bz2
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Patching
patching file gcc/jit/Make-lang.in
patching file gcc/jit/jit-playback.c
Hunk #1 succeeded at 2459 with fuzz 2 (offset 43 lines).
==> ../configure --build=x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/5.2.0 --libdir=/usr/local/Cel
==> make bootstrap
==> make install
==> Caveats
GCC has been built with multilib support. Notably, OpenMP may not work:
https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60670
If you need OpenMP support you may want to brew reinstall gcc --without-multilib
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/5.2.0: 1353 files, 248M, built in 52.4 minutes
```

It's seems the installation is ok! And then, I had uninstalled the **therubyracer** and **libv8** with gem. However when it comes to install the **therubyracer** (I didn't point the version when install or in **Gemfile**, and the **bundle** remind me the version **0.12.2** is need), there're comes the error:

```
➜  /Users/xxx/Documents/workspace/xxx git:(master) ✗ >gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.2'
Fetching: libv8-3.16.14.13.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing therubyracer:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
/Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20151230-50968-1yqguip.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile
Compiling v8 for x64
Using python 2.7.10
Using compiler: /usr/bin/c++ (clang version 6.1.0)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file:
/Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/atomicops_internals_x86_gcc.o has no symbols
In file included from ../src/accessors.cc:28:
In file included from ../src/v8.h:60:
In file included from ../src/objects-inl.h:38:
In file included from ../src/elements.h:33:
In file included from ../src/heap.h:35:
In file included from ../src/incremental-marking.h:33:
In file included from ../src/mark-compact.h:32:
../src/spaces.h:896:26: error: 'this' pointer cannot be null in well-defined C++ code; comparison may be assumed to always evaluate to true [-Werror,-Wtautological-undefined-compare]
bool exists() { return this != NULL && code_range_ != NULL; }
                     ^~~~    ~~~~
../src/spaces.h:898:9: error: 'this' pointer cannot be null in well-defined C++ code; comparison may be assumed to always evaluate to false [-Werror,-Wtautological-undefined-compare]
if (this == NULL || code_range_ == NULL) return false;
    ^~~~    ~~~~
2 errors generated.
make[1]: ***
[/Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/v8_base/src/accessors.o]
Error 1
make: *** [x64.release] Error 2
/Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/ext/libv8/location.rb:36:in `block in verify_installation!': libv8 did not install properly, expected binary v8 archive '
/Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_base.a'to exist, but it was not found (Libv8::Location::Vendor::ArchiveNotFound)
from
/Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/ext/libv8/location.rb:35:in `each'
from
/Uses/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/ext/libv8/location.rb:35:in `verify_installation!'
from
/Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/ext/libv8/location.rb:26:in `install!'
from extconf.rb:7:in `<main>'
GYP_GENERATORS=make \
build/gyp/gyp --generator-output="out" build/all.gyp \
              -Ibuild/standalone.gypi --depth=. \
              -Dv8_target_arch=x64 \
              -S.x64  -Dv8_enable_backtrace=1 -
Dv8_can_use_vfp2_instructions=true -Darm_fpu=vfpv2 -
Dv8_can_use_vfp3_instructions=true -Darm_fpu=vfpv3 -Dwerror=''
CXX(target)
/Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/allocation.o
CXX(target)
/Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/atomicops_internals_x86_gcc.o
CXX(target)
/Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/bignum.o
.................. (the follow error messages are similar to above)
```

Well, I'm wonder it's still the problem of the **libv8**! At first, I think it's maybe the problem of the version of **therubyracer**, so I had make a try to install the version **0.12.0**, unfortunately, there're the same errors. There're something strange, I mean the **libv8** is installed with the **therubyracer** in my case (see that from the error messages), but you're different with me. As your suggestion marked you install the **libv8** after you had installed the **therubyracer**, why they're different? Maybe it's relate to my **ruby** environment settings, here I posted my **Gemfile** configuration:

```
gem 'rails', '4.1.6'
gem 'mysql2', '0.3.18'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.4'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

gem 'jquery-rails','3.1.2'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '4.0.5'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

gem 'log4r', '1.1.9'
gem 'devise','3.4.1'
gem 'carrierwave', '0.10.0'
gem 'mini_magick', '3.6.0'
gem 'thin','1.6.2'
gem 'kaminari', '0.16.1'
gem 'factory_girl_rails'
gem 'httparty'
gem "select2-rails",'3.5.9.3'

group :test, :development do
    gem 'net-ssh', '2.7.0'
    gem 'capistrano', '2.12.0'
    gem 'capistrano-rbenv', '1.0.1'
    gem 'spring'
    gem 'magic_encoding', '0.0.2'
    gem 'rspec-rails', '3.2.0'
end
```

Comment: Did you figure this out?? Running into the same issue and it's killing me.

Comment: @frank-jorsn - I read the comment you left on the edit to my response (which got rejected). You said that the gcc install was successful, but if you look at your output again, you'll see that it wasn't: 'Error: Failed to download resource "gcc"'. I don't know too much about it, but make sure gcc is installed properly, and I think my solution will work for you. Good luck!

Comment: @Javid Jamae , well, I'm so sorry to reply your comment now. I'm so busy in a company's project that I have a long time not notice the stackoverflow notifications for me. I had read your comment, the gcc install problem you remind in comment is not quite right. I really installed the gcc in a right way, in the response I copied in your edit never say installed gcc failed, it's just download the one of resource failed but try another resource succeed. These can be checked in last response console content, I'm afraid you lost the details. I'll copy the console again for you below !

Comment: @Javid Jamae First time console: ==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/gcc-5.2.0.el_capitan.bottle.2.tar.gz
    ##################### 29.8%
    curl: (56) SSLRead() return error -9806
    Error: Failed to download resource "gcc"
    Download failed: https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/gcc-5.2.0.el_capitan.bottle.2.tar.gz
    Warning: Bottle installation failed: building from source.  Second time console: ==> Downloading http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/gcc/gcc-5.2.0/gcc-5.2.0.tar.bz2
    ==> Downloading from http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/gnu/gcc/gcc-5.2.0/gcc-5.2.0.tar.bz2  succeed!

Comment: @ Javid Jamae Here is the console for gcc version information: brew upgrade gcc
Error: gcc 5.2.0 already installed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the sam problem in OSX El Capitan. The steps I used to get over this were

First check if V8 is installed or not. I used brew to install it.

```
brew install homebrew/versions/v8-315
```

Try uninstalling libv8, therubyracer gems if some instance exists.

```
gem uninstall -a libv8
gem uninstall -a therubyracer
```

Then install the libv8 gem.

```
gem install libv8 -v '<<VERSION>>' -- --with-system-v8
```

Then install the therubyracer gem.

```
gem install therubyracer -v '<<VERSION>>' -- --with-v8-dir=$(brew --prefix v8-315)
```

Comment: So appreciated and so exciting the problem of mine-type about the dependency with the ***libv8***, ***v8*** and ***therubyracer*** got solved! @Pranshu Verma you really helped me a lot and let me know the relationships between the three. I'll make a conclusion of this based on my understanding, thanks again.

Comment: It worked for me and I omitted the `-v <<VERSION>>` arguments.

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me:

```
$ brew upgrade gcc

$ gem uninstall therubyracer

$ gem uninstall libv8

$ gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.0'
Fetching: therubyracer-0.12.0.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed therubyracer-0.12.0
1 gem installed

$ gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3' -- --with-system-v8
Fetching: libv8-3.16.14.3.gem (100%)
Building native extensions with: '--with-system-v8'
This could take a while...
Successfully installed libv8-3.16.14.3
1 gem installed
```

References:

- https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer/issues/398
- https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer/issues/288#issuecomment-63923606

Comment: Second that.. After much struggle this worked for me!

Comment: Third that. I tried more than a dozen solutions in this thread and many others, before this finally worked. I actually had to do:

    `$ brew install gcc`

... which took 35 minutes to complete, but then therubyracer finally submitted to being installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, updating therubyracer to the latest version solved the issue.

Try:

```
bundle update therubyracer
```

If you also have issues with libv8 then try:

```
bundle update libv8
```

Comment: Hi, @user1894919 ! Maybe your solution is a good way to solve the version's problem of the **therubyracer** and "libv8", but  it's can't solve my problem. You should know I have the problem to **install** the **therubyracer**, it's means I have never install the **therubyracer** into my computer, so the **update** way is not a good idea for me.  Here is the error messages: **$bundle update therubyracer**  -> **This Bundle hasn't been installed yet. Run `bundle install` to update and install the bundled gems.**  Thanks anyway !

Comment: Hi @frankjorsn in this case try to edit the Gemfile to use the latest version of therubyracer and also libv8 if you need and after that run bundle install, this might work for you. Sorry the delay, I've only seen your reply now.