# Error installing Nokogiri gem on Mac OS X

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, nokogiri

I was trying to install a connector for `Rally` and `bugzilla` on my Mac OSx. While running the install script, it tries to install the gems and it looks for the `libxml2` which is already present on my machine.

This happens when it tries to install nokogiri.

This is the transcript:

```
Building native extensions with: '--use-system-libraries'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150121-48754-wgouyu.rb extconf.rb --use-system-libraries
Extracting libxml2-2.8.0.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/ports/libxml2/2.8.0... OK
Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.8.0... OK
Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.8.0... OK
Running 'install' for libxml2 2.8.0... OK
Activating libxml2 2.8.0 (from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.1/ports/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/libxml2/2.8.0)...
Extracting libxslt-1.1.26.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/ports/libxslt/1.1.26... OK
Running 'configure' for libxslt 1.1.26... OK
Running 'compile' for libxslt 1.1.26... OK
Running 'install' for libxslt 1.1.26... OK
Activating libxslt 1.1.26 (from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.1/ports/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/libxslt/1.1.26)...
checking for libxml/parser.h... yes
checking for libxslt/xslt.h... yes
checking for libexslt/exslt.h... yes
checking for iconv_open() in iconv.h... no
checking for iconv_open() in -liconv... yes
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -lxml2... no
-----
`  libxml2 is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials /installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.`
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers. Check the mkmf.log file for more details. You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --with-iconv-dir
    --without-iconv-dir
    --with-iconv-include
    --without-iconv-include=${iconv-dir}/include
    --with-iconv-lib
    --without-iconv-lib=${iconv-dir}/lib
    --with-xml2-dir
    --without-xml2-dir
    --with-xml2-include
    --without-xml2-include=${xml2-dir}/include
    --with-xml2-lib
    --without-xml2-lib=${xml2-dir}/lib
    --with-xslt-dir
    --without-xslt-dir
    --with-xslt-include
    --without-xslt-include=${xslt-dir}/include
    --with-xslt-lib
    --without-xslt-lib=${xslt-dir}/lib
    --with-libxslt-config
    --without-libxslt-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --with-libxml-2.0-config
    --without-libxml-2.0-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --with-libiconv-config
    --without-libiconv-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --with-iconvlib
    --without-iconvlib
    --with-xml2lib
    --without-xml2lib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-13/2.0.0/nokogiri-1.6.1/gem_make.out
```

I tried so many options like installing the command line tools by running the below command.
    `xcode-select --install`

Adding the symbolic links to gcc compliler

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/llvm-gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
```

I have been struggling for the past two days. Any help is highly apperciated.

Comment: try gem install nokogiri --pre

Comment: Have you run `brew install libxml2`?

Comment: @edgar i already have libxml2 . . when i try to install `brew install libxml2` it says libxml2 is already installed.

Comment: @reko no still same error am getting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using brew use this in the terminal:

```
brew unlink gcc-4.2      # you might not need this step
gem uninstall nokogiri
xcode-select --install
gem install nokogiri
```

If this didn't work please check "[Installing Nokogiri on OSX 10.10 Yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24091869/installing-nokogiri-on-osx-10-10-yosemite)"

Comment: Please look at the other versions as well.

Answer (score 5):

Solved the issue with the command

```
sudo ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.1'
```

thanks for the link pointed out by mohamed abd.

Comment: You are welcome also please mark the question as solved

Comment: Actually you should accept this answer since just a link containing the answer is not a good answer. This answer looks way better to me.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
sudo gem install nokogiri --no-rdoc --no-ri
```