# Bump nokogiri from 1.11.4 to 1.12.5 #2

Tags: github

I made an account this morning on GitHub, and got this mail concerning a severity security issue.

I operate on iMAC operating intel (old machine).
Is this a concern that should be fixed before proceed with my first repository?
I'm quite new in Git.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of email should only be sent for existing repositories analyzed automatically by GitHub and its [Dependabot service](https://github.com/dependabot/dependabot-core).

It can lead to the automatic creation of this [PR (Pull Request)](https://github.com/dependabot/dependabot-script/pull/699/files) on an existing project.

Since you don't have one, you should not have to do anything for now.

Still, make sure that locally, you have the right version of that library, as shown in "[Error installing Nokogiri gem on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28061123/6309)".