# Cannot install cocoa pods after uninstalling, results in error

Tags: ios, terminal, installation, cocoapods

I removed cocoa pods because it claimed it had installed, but kept saying the command pod wasn't found afterward. When trying to reinstall cocoapods (`sudo gem install cocoa pods -v`) I get this error:

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
>       Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/pod

[image: Screenshot for error]

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm using an administrator account, how would I go about fixing permissions?

Comment: 'pod' doesn't exist in /usr/bin

Answer (score 424):

As it has been pointed out [below by Ramesh Ramchandaran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31783856/4029561), this is a cleaner way of doing it, instead of getting around the Security features of OS X.

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

---

## Original Answer

I'm assuming you're running OS X 10.11.

This is happening because Apple has enabled rootless on the new install.

If you type:

```
sudo nvram boot-args="rootless=0"; sudo reboot
```

in `terminal.app`, your computer will reboot with it disabled.

Once that is done, type:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods -V
```

the `-V` is for verbose and will spit out any errors if they happen.

Comment: Thanks! The combined command (including the `sudo reboot`) failed for me and froze the computer on several different attempts. Hard resetting did not keep the nvram settings. I had to run the first command until the semi-colon, and then restart from Apple menu. Then, cocoapods could install. Thank you!!!

Comment: in El Capitan GM the first install (sudo gem install cocoapods -V) didn't work, the second one did though!

Comment: what's the downside of disabling rootless?

Comment: The downside is Security

Comment: I had this issue after updating my Mac Mini from Yosemite to El Capitan.

Comment: How to choose a older version in this condition?

Answer (score 162):

As rootless does not affect /usr/local/bin, the following succeeds:

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

Any caveats?

Comment: This is a much better solution than mine.

Comment: how long it will take to install.it is taking more time.

Answer (score 4):

Using **home-brew** or custom **$GEM_HOME** can help resolving the issue.
I did clean installation of ruby with *brew*:

`brew install ruby`

Now the `gem` stuff seem to happen relative to my `/usr/local/bin*`, which is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend installing all your gems into your `.gem` folder in your home folder to avoid using `sudo` or a ruby version manager as other people suggest.

All you have to do is update your `.bash_profile` by adding these 2 lines. (Don‘t forget to restart your terminal after applying these changes)

```
export GEM_HOME=~/.gem
export PATH="$GEM_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score -1):

After updgrading from Yosemite to El Capitan ( 10.11.4), I kept getting the below error message while trying to 'reinstall' Cocoapods ( after trying out pretty  much all the solutions under different Stackoverflow threads and the Cocoapods issue-page itself, for the same issue)

```
"Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods' (>= 0) in any repository"
```

However, quit terminal, restarted system, created new Xcode project from the scratch and then when i did `'pod install'`, it worked.

Note: I was trying to use  Alamofire and SwiftyJson cocoapods