# Cocoapods on el capitan

Tags: ios, objective-c, terminal, cocoapods, osx-elcapitan

I've just update my OSX to `El Capitan`. Now when I want to update my PodFile I get this error:

```
pod: command not found
```

Any help here?

Comment: Reinstall cocoapods?

Comment: I even can't install it. I get this: ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/pod

Comment: sudo gem install cocoapods

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30812777/cannot-install-cocoa-pods-after-uninstalling-results-in-error

Answer (score 15, accepted):

binstubs are no longer installed into `/usr/bin`.

If you are upgrading from Yosemite simply uninstall cocoapods (`gem uninstall cocoapods` or `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods`) and then run the following:

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods
[...]
1 gem installed
$ export PATH=$PATH:/Library/Ruby/bin
$ pod --version
0.38.2
```

Comment: Uninstall was a good idea, but is doesn't solve the real problem. See comment on hyunc's answer below.

Answer (score 16):

The installation in /usr/local/bin worked perfectly:

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

but only with adding addtional rights I was able to access it

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/local/bin
```

Answer (score 6):

It worked for me for the bug when run Cocoapods on El Capitan 10.11:

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

Comment: This question is a duplicate of several others, where this is the preferred solution

Comment: In my PATH didn't has "/usr/local/bin" and so it didn't work, to resolve my problem i added manually in my .bash_profile. "export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:", or if you will prefer can run in terminal.

Answer (score -2):

The same happened for me, `sudo gem install cocoapods` solved the issue