# Cocoa Pods not updating pods on El Capitan

Tags: ios, cocoapods, osx-elcapitan

I've upgraded to El Capitan and since then I can't update my pods.

```
$ pod update
-bash: pod: command not found
```

So I've tried to reinstall CocoaPods and got this:

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/xcodeproj
```

I am the administrator on this computer. Why is this happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can not perform \`pod install\` under el capitan (15A279b)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32810808/can-not-perform-pod-install-under-el-capitan-15a279b)

Answer (score 201, accepted):

This is caused by the new [System integrity protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection) feature introduced in El Capitan. It restricts even administrators from writing to `/usr/bin`.

Your best option would be to install gems without needing `sudo`. There is a good [guide on how to do that](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#sudo-less-installation):

```
export GEM_HOME=$HOME/.gem
export PATH=$GEM_HOME/bin:$PATH

gem install cocoapods
```

Comment: @Pavlo Shadov sudo gem uninstall cocoapods can uninstall the old CocoaPods with a option prompt. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

From [CocoaPods issues 3736](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3736)

1. Uninstall all instances of cocopods (just to be safe and keep things clean) see [fully uninstall Cocoapods](https://superuser.com/a/686319/140556)

   ```
   sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
   ```

   or even better fully uninstall all components (and select All versions for each)

   ```
   gem list --local | grep cocoapods | awk '{print $1}' | xargs sudo gem uninstall
   ```
2. Install again

   ```
   sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
   ```
3. Change access permission

   ```
   sudo chmod +rx /usr/local/bin/
   ```

Answer (score 7):

This should work for you

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

#### [Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/xcodeproj #3692](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3692)

> For whatever reason, the rootless stuff seems less restrictive when one simply upgrades the system. I could sudo gem install cocoapods just fine on a machine upgraded from 10.10 - however, binstubs are no longer installed into /usr/bin:

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods
[...]
1 gem installed
$ export PATH=$PATH:/Library/Ruby/bin
$ pod --version
0.37.2
```

> We have heard from some users that they receive this error when doing a system-wide installation:
>
> `ERROR: While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
>   Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/pod`
>
> We aren't sure why gem behaves differently on some systems, but this can be solved by passing `-n /usr/local/bin` to the install command, so that the pod executable gets installed there.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the original question/problem:

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted
```

I found I had the same problem with *several* GEMS, so I generalized the recognized answer ([Keith Smiley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/902968/keith-smiley)) to update ALL local gems... (on El Capitan with rootless in force)

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin/    # this command installs
$ sudo gem update -n /usr/local/bin/    # this command updates all local gems
```

This works well and will spit out a verbose log of all updates and errors.

I saw *many* errors. They were all 'unable to convert' errors. Parsing many docs will encounter a "skipping" error... like this:

```
$ unable to convert "\xCF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/jazzy... skipping
```

I believe these skipping errors are not problems.

CocoaPods will be updated during this process, along with all the other local GEMS, depending on how current your local GEMS are. I believe this is the best way to handle the rootless issue (which is the cause of the problem).

Answer (score 2):

Your best option for installing Pods for custom and standard installation
Refer the Link :https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3692

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you install Xcode Command Line tools again ? That solved my problem. You need to select Command Line tool in Xcode preferences(Locations) and than install cocoa pods.

Comment: I have Xcode 7.0.1 selected for Command Line Tools. Should I install something else?

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked with:
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods --pre