# Updating cocoapods for AWS Mobile iOS SDK

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, rubygems, cocoapods

I previous went through the process in Feb. 2016 to install the AWS iOS SDK using cocoapods. Everything got up and running. But now returning to my project 2 months later I run it and get:

```
/Users/cdub/Developer/AppName/Pods/Headers/Public/AWSCognito/AWSCognitoSyncService.h:198:4: Type arguments cannot be applied to non-parameterized class 'AWSTask'
```

I am trying to update the cocoapods and I have cocoapods downloaded and previously installed at:

```
/Users/cdub/Software/ruby/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0
```

But now I run this and get this in the terminal:

```
pod update
-bash: pod: command not found
```

What am I missing?

Comment: see this link once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32810808/can-not-perform-pod-install-under-el-capitan-15a279b/32900319

Comment: so i need to reinstall it?

Comment: see this one for sample https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/issues/297