# How can I clean up this Source Control mess?

Tags: xcode, git, github

A life situation took me away from writing an iPhone app almost a year ago. At the time, I was using Xcode 6, and using Snapshots for version control. I'm a single hobbyist developer, and it seemed overkill to use Git. This may have been a stupid mistake, because I didn't set the app up with a repo.

Now that I've returned to the app, I find that the Snapshots feature has been removed in Xcode 7. Notwithstanding my annoyance over this, I tried to create a local repo and add my project to it. I did this using GitHub Desktop. The repo appears to have been created, but also appears not to register changes, i.e., when I try to examine changed and committed files via Source Control > History, the files appear to be identical.

I've spent the last 3 days trying to understand what went wrong, searching the web and SO, but haven't found anything directly addressing my problem. I've tried eliminating the repo so I can try creating a new one. Regardless of what I try, the local repo (which appears not to work as expected) persists. I've considered creating a new project (with Source Control activated) and dragging my files into it, but the matter is complicated by the fact that the project is in a workspace, along with several pods, and I'm afraid of breaking everything.

It's humiliating to admit it, but I'm really flying blind. I would be very grateful it if someone can tell me how to get back on track.

All help appreciated...

**Edit:**

Following @Paulw11's suggestion in his comment, I think I'm getting close, but am having problems with cocoapods.

The first problem was with the El Capitan/CocoaPods conundrum, which I believe I have successfully fixed by reinstalling CocoaPods following instructions found in the accepted answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32810808/can-not-perform-pod-install-under-el-capitan-15a279b/32986080).

Now, however, when I try to install my pods, I get this:

```
[!] No `Podfile' found in the project directory.
```

But there IS a Podfile in the project, unless I've done something wrong by dragging it from the Finder into the Project Navigator.

Additionally, I'm confused as to whether I should navigate to the xcodeproj file itself or to the Folder containing it. I get the same result, either way.

Here is the Terminal readout from my last two attempts at installing the pods:

```
14 gems installed
Tim-Jones-MacBook-Pro:~ timjones$ /Users/timjones/Desktop/WMMG\ 4\ folder/WMMG\ 4/WMMG\ 4.xcodeproj pod install
-bash: /Users/timjones/Desktop/WMMG 4 folder/WMMG 4/WMMG 4.xcodeproj: is a directory
Tim-Jones-MacBook-Pro:~ timjones$ /Users/timjones/Desktop/WMMG\ 4\ folder/WMMG\ 4 pod install
-bash: /Users/timjones/Desktop/WMMG 4 folder/WMMG 4: is a directory
Tim-Jones-MacBook-Pro:~ timjones$ pod update
[!] No `Podfile' found in the project directory.
Tim-Jones-MacBook-Pro:~ timjones$ /Users/timjones/Desktop/WMMG\ 4\ folder/WMMG\ 4/WMMG\ 4.xcodeproj pod update
-bash: /Users/timjones/Desktop/WMMG 4 folder/WMMG 4/WMMG 4.xcodeproj: is a directory
Tim-Jones-MacBook-Pro:~ timjones$ pod update
[!] No `Podfile' found in the project directory.
Tim-Jones-MacBook-Pro:~ timjones$
```

Another thing worth mentioning is that, although I created this new project with Source Control NOT enabled (per suggestion in comment), I nevertheless see that Xcode somehow has created a repo (or is using a repo created, ignorantly, for an earlier version). Frustrating because this is exactly one of the things I'm trying to avoid by creating a new project.

I admit being a novice with the command line, although I have been successful with it in the past by following instructions.

Can someone please help me get past this bump?

**Update**

Ok, I got the pods installed in the new project, but the repo appears regardless. So I decided to delete all previous versions (after making a backup, of course) and repeating the process with a new project. Now I'm back to the same inability to install pods as before `(No`Podfile' found in the project directory.)`and`(-bash: /Users/timjones/Desktop/WMMG 5 folder/WMMG 5: is a directory)`

It's not at all clear to me why Terminal keeps warning me that these items are directory. Here is the most recent result in Terminal:

```
Tim-Jones-MacBook-Pro:~ timjones$ pod update
[!] No `Podfile' found in the project directory.
Tim-Jones-MacBook-Pro:~ timjones$ /Users/timjones/Desktop/WMMG\ 5\ folder/WMMG\ 5 pod update
-bash: /Users/timjones/Desktop/WMMG 5 folder/WMMG 5: is a directory
Tim-Jones-MacBook-Pro:~ timjones$ /Users/timjones/Desktop/WMMG\ 5\ folder/WMMG\ 5/WMMG\ 5.xcodeproj pod update
-bash: /Users/timjones/Desktop/WMMG 5 folder/WMMG 5/WMMG 5.xcodeproj: is a directory
Tim-Jones-MacBook-Pro:~ timjones$ pod update
[!] No `Podfile' found in the project directory.
Tim-Jones-MacBook-Pro:~ timjones$ /Users/timjones/Desktop/WMMG\ 5\ folder/WMMG\ 5 pod update
-bash: /Users/timjones/Desktop/WMMG 5 folder/WMMG 5: is a directory
Tim-Jones-MacBook-Pro:~ timjones$ /Users/timjones/Desktop/WMMG\ 5\ folder/WMMG\ 5/WMMG\ 5.xcodeproj pod install
-bash: /Users/timjones/Desktop/WMMG 5 folder/WMMG 5/WMMG 5.xcodeproj: is a directory
Tim-Jones-MacBook-Pro:~ timjones$ pod update
[!] No `Podfile' found in the project directory.
Tim-Jones-MacBook-Pro:~ timjones$ pod init
[!] No Xcode project found, please specify one
Tim-Jones-MacBook-Pro:~ timjones$ /Users/timjones/Desktop/WMMG\ 5\ folder/WMMG\ 5 pod init
-bash: /Users/timjones/Desktop/WMMG 5 folder/WMMG 5: is a directory
Tim-Jones-MacBook-Pro:~ timjones$
```

Comment: I would start a new project in a new directory but don't enable source control. Copy your existing source files over and add them to the project. Copy your pod file over and run pod install. Once you have your project running then create a free account on bitbucket.org and create a new repo there. They will give you the command line you need to create a local repo and link it to the bitbucket repo. Xcode will recognise this when you open the workspace. I would add the podfile to version control but not the Pods directory.

Comment: Many thanks for this tip! Im in the process of trying to implement, but hit a snag with the command line late last night. Will respond as soon as I have something worth reporting. Thanks again!