# Get data from JSON file with iOS and swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have this JSON file:

```
      var Point :

      [   
         {
         "id": 1,
         "name": "A",
         "LastUpdate": 1468011600,
         "position": [36.8656974, 10.1687314]},

         {
         "id": 1,
         "name": "A",
         "LastUpdate": 1468397003,
         "position": [36.9009882, 10.3009531]
         },
         {
         "id": 1,
         "name": "A",
         "LastUpdate": 1467590490,
         "position": [37.1691357, 10.0349865]
         }
          ]
```

and I need to read this data in my viewController, I tried to work with **SwiftyJSON** but I failed.
PS: I code with **swift** and not objective-C
Any solutions?

Comment: You can use `NSJSONSerialization` to transform the String JSON into a Array.

Comment: Can you provide some code here?

Comment: Have you ever came across NSJSONSerialization

Comment: yeah, but that didn't work with me..
do {
        let jsonDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as! [String: AnyObject]
        completion(jsonDictionary)
    } catch let error {
        print("JSON Serialization failed. Error: \(error)")
    }

Comment: Does the data start with "var Point :" ? Isn't it "var Point =" ?

Comment: You deserialized it as a Dictionary when at top level it's an array ! So `let jsonArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as! [AnyObject]` instead?

Comment: Can you try to use JsonParser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [this great library](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON). This library provide parsing from JSON to Dictionary very simple (just 1-2 line of code).

P.S.
Also i recommended use [this library](https://github.com/ibireme/YYModel) to mapping Dictionary to Object

**UPDATE**
To install swiftyJSON in podfile

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'SwiftyJSON'
```

Then `sudo pod install`

Comment: i can't install swiftyJSON :( 
-bash: pod: command not found

Comment: You can download sources from github or [install pods](https://cocoapods.org)

Comment: i installed COCOAPODS and then i created the podfile, then?

Comment: Then in podfile write `platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!
pod 'SwiftyJSON'`

Important **use_frameworks!** and then `sudo pod install`

Comment: I got this:
sudo: pod: command not found

Comment: Hm.., [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14204067/3551959) post tell to upgrade Ruby and [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32810808/can-not-perform-pod-install-under-el-capitan-15a279b) tell how fix for Cocoapods error on El Capitan

Comment: that works! thank you

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply using [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire). It's simple framework and you can install it using Cocoa pods. Here is the example of using Alamofire:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
         .responseJSON { response in
             print(response.request)  // original URL request
             print(response.response) // URL response
             print(response.data)     // server data
             print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

             if let JSON = response.result.value {
                 print("JSON: \(JSON)")
             }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to convert string to NSDictionary

```
func convertStringToDictionary(text: String) -> [String:AnyObject]? {
  if let data = text.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
    do {
        return try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }
  }
  return nil
}
```

To remove the syntax errors from your submitted code replace curly braces with square brackets.

```
var Point = [   
     [
     "id": 1,
     "name": "A",
     "LastUpdate": 1468011600,
     "position": [36.8656974, 10.1687314]],

     [
     "id": 1,
     "name": "A",
     "LastUpdate": 1468397003,
     "position": [36.9009882, 10.3009531]
     ],
     [
     "id": 1,
     "name": "A",
     "LastUpdate": 1467590490,
     "position": [37.1691357, 10.0349865]
     ]
  ]
```

Comment: Deserializing the particular JSON in the question will return `nil`.

Comment: Yes, because that's not a valid json object. It's root is missing. try to wrap it like this. `{"root":"your existing string"}`.

To be more specific, `{"root":"[ {"id": 1, "name": "A",...}, ... ]"}`.

Comment: Apart from the confusion that the JSON doesn't match the variable declaration the root object of JSON is not required to be a dictionary.

Comment: Your problem is, your submitted code give syntax errors?

Comment: Use `try?` instead of `do {try...} catch{...}`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30480777/2227743