# Using CryptoSwift Library with Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, cryptoswift

I am trying to use the CrpytoSwift Library in Xcode, and I have tried many tutorials to add it to my project, however when i import it it throws the 'module not found error'. Is there something Im missing? (I've included the links I followed below.

1. [Cannot install cocoa pods after uninstalling, results in error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30812777/cannot-install-cocoa-pods-after-uninstalling-results-in-error/30851030#30851030)
2. http://blog.krzyzanowskim.com/2015/01/28/how-to-install-cryptoswift/

EDIT:
I've also uploaded a screenshot of my xcode project directory tree.[Xcode Directory Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlzGp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to remove the 'module not found error' the project needs to be cleaned and built again for it to recognize the added packages(pods).