# Having Hello A ssl problems while installing cocoapods

Tags: swift, ssl, cocoapods

hello guys i am having problems wile trying to install cocoapods in el captian i just updated yesterday and cant install the cocoapods due to this error

[terminal results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaw8P.jpg)

im kinda new to mac and xcode and everything  i have already looked at all the answers that might have helped like

[Cannot install cocoa pods after uninstalling, results in error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30812777/cannot-install-cocoa-pods-after-uninstalling-results-in-error?answertab=active#tab-top)

and entered the codes bud didnt get any result on it so if u could explain the issue in a simple way that would be great thanks

Comment: i think this thread might be the answer and i tryed understanding the steps but i didnt have any luck with it any ideas on this ? https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/522

Answer (score 0):

hey after some research and asking from some friends this is what they offered me

Sounds like there is some SSL issue in your RubyGems installation, maybe [this](http://ga.be/blog/2013/10/02/fixing-rubygems-ssl-issues-certificate-verify-failed/) can help. Another option is to use the OS X app as installation method instead: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods-app/releases/tag/0.39.0

i used the app and it solved my problem 
thanks anyways