# sudo gem install cocoapods Stuck

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I can't use sudo gem install cocoapods and it has no response. I have even removed all cocoapods and try again. it is not okay.

Some link in stackoverflow say I need to do like this. It is still not okay.

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local
```

How shall I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
export GEM_HOME=~/.gems
export PATH=$GEM_HOME/bin:$PATH

gem install cocoapods
```

Comment: providing an answer, try to give more details about what is the solution and why would it work :)

Comment: Maybe you are running OS X 10.11.      This is happening because Apple has enabled rootless on the new install.     You can look up [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30812777/cannot-install-cocoa-pods-after-uninstalling-results-in-error/30851030#30851030).