# Google mobile ads in unity (iOS) shows error

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, ads

I'm using google mobile ads in unity (iOS). I take the build in Xcode during linking.

It shows the following errors:

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_GADURequestInterstitial", referenced from:
      _Externs_GADURequestInterstitial_m133 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _IOSInterstitialClient_LoadAd_m201 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADURequestInterstitial_m133_MethodInfo, _Externs_GADURequestInterstitial_m133 )
  "_GADUCreateInterstitial", referenced from:
      _Externs_GADUCreateInterstitial_m129 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUCreateInterstitial_m129, _Externs_GADUCreateInterstitial_m129_MethodInfo )
  "_GADURequestBannerAd", referenced from:
      _Externs_GADURequestBannerAd_m128 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _IOSBannerClient_LoadAd_m162 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADURequestBannerAd_m128, _Externs_GADURequestBannerAd_m128_MethodInfo )
  "_GADUShowBannerView", referenced from:
      _Externs_GADUShowBannerView_m126 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _IOSBannerClient_ShowBannerView_m163 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUShowBannerView_m126_MethodInfo, _Externs_GADUShowBannerView_m126 )
  "_GADUHideBannerView", referenced from:
      _Externs_GADUHideBannerView_m125 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _IOSBannerClient_HideBannerView_m164 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUHideBannerView_m125_MethodInfo, _Externs_GADUHideBannerView_m125 )
  "_GADUSetBannerCallbacks", referenced from:
      _Externs_GADUSetBannerCallbacks_m124 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUSetBannerCallbacks_m124, _Externs_GADUSetBannerCallbacks_m124_MethodInfo )
  "_GADUCreateBannerView", referenced from:
      _Externs_GADUCreateBannerView_m122 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUCreateBannerView_m122_MethodInfo, _Externs_GADUCreateBannerView_m122 )
  "_GADUShowInterstitial", referenced from:
      _Externs_GADUShowInterstitial_m132 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _IOSInterstitialClient_ShowInterstitial_m203 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUShowInterstitial_m132, _Externs_GADUShowInterstitial_m132_MethodInfo )
  "_GADUAddKeyword", referenced from:
      _Externs_GADUAddKeyword_m116 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUAddKeyword_m116, _Externs_GADUAddKeyword_m116_MethodInfo )
  "_GADURelease", referenced from:
      _Externs_GADURelease_m121 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _IOSBannerClient_set_BannerViewPtr_m160 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _IOSBannerClient_CreateBannerView_m161 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _IOSBannerClient_LoadAd_m162 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _IOSBannerClient_DestroyBannerView_m165 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _IOSInterstitialClient_set_InterstitialPtr_m199 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _IOSInterstitialClient_CreateInterstitialAd_m200 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      ...
     (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADURelease_m121_MethodInfo, _Externs_GADURelease_m121 )
  "_GADURemoveBannerView", referenced from:
      _Externs_GADURemoveBannerView_m127 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _IOSBannerClient_DestroyBannerView_m165 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADURemoveBannerView_m127, _Externs_GADURemoveBannerView_m127_MethodInfo )
  "_GADUTagForChildDirectedTreatment", referenced from:
      _Externs_GADUTagForChildDirectedTreatment_m119 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _IOSBannerClient_LoadAd_m162 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _IOSInterstitialClient_LoadAd_m201 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUTagForChildDirectedTreatment_m119_MethodInfo, _Externs_GADUTagForChildDirectedTreatment_m119 )
  "_GADUSetInterstitialCallbacks", referenced from:
      _Externs_GADUSetInterstitialCallbacks_m130 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUSetInterstitialCallbacks_m130, _Externs_GADUSetInterstitialCallbacks_m130_MethodInfo )
  "_GADUCreateSmartBannerView", referenced from:
      _Externs_GADUCreateSmartBannerView_m123 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUCreateSmartBannerView_m123, _Externs_GADUCreateSmartBannerView_m123_MethodInfo )
  "_GADUSetGender", referenced from:
      _Externs_GADUSetGender_m118 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _IOSBannerClient_LoadAd_m162 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _IOSInterstitialClient_LoadAd_m201 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUSetGender_m118, _Externs_GADUSetGender_m118_MethodInfo )
  "_GADUSetExtra", referenced from:
      _Externs_GADUSetExtra_m120 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUSetExtra_m120_MethodInfo, _Externs_GADUSetExtra_m120 )
  "_GADUSetBirthday", referenced from:
      _Externs_GADUSetBirthday_m117 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _IOSBannerClient_LoadAd_m162 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _IOSInterstitialClient_LoadAd_m201 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUSetBirthday_m117, _Externs_GADUSetBirthday_m117_MethodInfo )
  "_GADUAddTestDevice", referenced from:
      _Externs_GADUAddTestDevice_m115 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUAddTestDevice_m115_MethodInfo, _Externs_GADUAddTestDevice_m115 )
  "_GADUInterstitialReady", referenced from:
      _Externs_GADUInterstitialReady_m131 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _IOSInterstitialClient_IsLoaded_m202 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUInterstitialReady_m131_MethodInfo, _Externs_GADUInterstitialReady_m131 )
  "_GADUCreateRequest", referenced from:
      _Externs_GADUCreateRequest_m114 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _IOSBannerClient_LoadAd_m162 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
      _IOSInterstitialClient_LoadAd_m201 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUCreateRequest_m114, _Externs_GADUCreateRequest_m114_MethodInfo )
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Have you tried to set up library's settings in the editor? iOS platform and "Any CPU" should be suitable

Comment: its not working i changed the architecture to armv7 getting same errors                    undefined symbols for architecture armv7

Comment: Have you find any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem it's that unity It's not able to run/find the Cocoa pods main files and install the Pods automatically. 
That is what I did to fix the problem:

1. Be sure that on unity you don't have any message about the impossibility to build pods file because pods it's missing inside Unity. If that's the case, you need to update/install cocoa pods into your mac. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30812777/cannot-install-cocoa-pods-after-uninstalling-results-in-error/30851030#30851030) some tips about how to do that on OS El Capitan. But generally by run this command you should be fine:

   sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods

Then close and reopen unity.

2. Open you Xcode folder, you should have a file that it's something like: "`youProjectName.xcworkspace`". If you have it, open it, if not that means that something when wrong when Unity try to run the PodFile inside you project. Try to run the PodInstall manually, you can do it by open the command line, go to your project folder and rune the command: `pod install`. Be sure that the Pods will be installed correctly and without any errors. Now you should see the "`youProjectName.xcworkspace`"un your main directory.
3. Id Steps 2 doesn't work try to deletes all the Pods files and directory and then add and install you own Pods as indicated [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start?authuser=1#streamlined_using_cocoapods).
4. If that still doesn't work you only solution it's use an old versione of the Unity adMob sdks that you can download [here](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/releases). And [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GAKnpBKKPds) tutorial to manually install the the google ad mob sdk without using the PodsFile.