# How to switch between versions of cocoapods?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

Is there a way to switch between versions of cocoapods?

This is what I get when I try to remove one:

```
Select gem to uninstall:
 1. cocoapods-0.29.0
 2. cocoapods-0.34.4
 3. cocoapods-0.35.0
 4. cocoapods-0.36.0
 5. cocoapods-0.37.2
 6. cocoapods-0.38.2
 7. cocoapods-0.39.0
 8. All versions
```

I just select the number of one I need to uninstall. Is there a way to set **current version** of cocoapods?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install specific version with this command example,

```
sudo gem install cocoapods -v 0.36.0
```

Or uninstall all the version , so it will be good if only latest version is available.

check this . [how-to-fully-uninstall-the-cocoapods-from-the-mac-machine](https://superuser.com/questions/686317/how-to-fully-uninstall-the-cocoapods-from-the-mac-machine)

and install cocoapod again with sudo gem install cocoapods command.

Check here :- [How to install coocapod](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32642692/4910767)

Answer (score 3):

To get some previous version of cocoapods use this:

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods -v 1.4.0
```

Why using `-n` flag? Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30851030/1292099)!

To install pods using `1.4.0` use this:

```
pod _1.4.0_ install
```