# 'sudo gem install cocoapods' doesn't work on El Capitan 10.11.4 , ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods' (>= 0) in any repository

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, osx-elcapitan

Upgrading from Yosemite to El Capitan seem to have wiped out the already installed CocoaPods. When I pod install Alamofire/SwiftyJson, it says `'Pod command not found'`, and as per the stackoverflow solutions I uninstalled cocoapods and trying to reinstall it with the commands

```
 - sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
 - sudo gem install cocoapods
```

I get the error:

> "Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods' (>= 0) in any repository"

Did go through ALL the solutions mentioned by the Gurus under the issue
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3736

mainly tried this which seem to have worked for many. still doesn't work for me.

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

tried modifying the permissions etc as per the solutions provided in the above link and the SO link

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30812777/cannot-install-cocoa-pods-after-uninstalling-results-in-error?rq=1
```

Nothing works, EVERYTHING leads to the same error
"Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods' (>= 0) in any repository"

I have also raised a issue on

```
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5232
```

Comment: Donot Mark it as duplicate as none of the solutions in SO/Cocoapods Issues link works. Appreciate if someone can really get to the gut of it and help me fix it

Answer (score 60):

I faced the same problem and it was fixed by using the following command

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods --source http://rubygems.org
```

Answer (score 3):

I struggled with same issue 1 week, finally this works for me

**Disable IPv6 and try again** with **sudo gem install cocoapods --source http://rubygems.org**

Issues seems with network

Few more details give on rugby gems forum - https://help.rubygems.org/discussions/problems/31074-timeout-error