# Cocoapods on Mac unable to install "Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods' (>= 0)"

Tags: ios, ruby, dns, cocoapods

I have one office Mac running MacOS 10.13.2 and Ruby 2.2.1 and it is unable to install or run cocoapods via gems. `sudo gem install cocoapods` returns the error below. I compared the proxy and DNS configuration and it is identical to other macs that can install successfully.

```
▶ ping https://rubygems.org
ping: cannot resolve https://rubygems.org: Unknown host
```

**What is causing cocoapods installation to fail with the cryptic  no such name (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz) error message?**

I tried the answer from this question: ['sudo gem install cocoapods' doesn't work on ElCapitan 10.11.4 , ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods' (>= 0) in any repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36972339/sudo-gem-install-cocoapods-doesnt-work-on-elcapitan-10-11-4-error-could-no)

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods --source http://rubygems.org
```

> ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods' (>= 0), here is why:
>             Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - no such name (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
>             Unable to download data from http://rubygems.org/ - no such name (http://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gem cannot access rubygems.org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49800432/gem-cannot-access-rubygems-org)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was resolved by connecting to a mobile hotspot and updating ruby through that.