# gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc error cannot install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, nokogiri

Trying to run the command `gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc` to install rails. I'm currently running `ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-darwin14]` on Yosemite (Mac OS X v10.10.3). I have tried reinstalling Nokogiri from this article: [Installing Nokogiri on OSX 10.10 Yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24091869/installing-nokogiri-on-osx-10-10-yosemite) and Nokogiri installs just fine. However, every time I try to install Rails, I get the exact same error. I have installed libxml2 and libxslt without any problems and linked them just like every tutorial has showed me. I'm at my wits ends as to what I might try next. Any suggestions?

The exact output from `gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc` is as follows:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/Neophile/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150620-30888-546cip.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... yes
checking for iconv... yes
************************************************************************
IMPORTANT NOTICE:

Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxml2-2.9.2
with the following patches applied:
    - 0001-Revert-Missing-initialization-for-the-catalog-module.patch
    - 0002-Fix-missing-entities-after-CVE-2014-3660-fix.patch

Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security
updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want
to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and
reinstall nokogiri as follows:

    gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
        [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
        [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

    bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install

Note, however, that nokogiri is not fully compatible with arbitrary
versions of libxml2 provided by OS/package vendors.
************************************************************************
Extracting libxml2-2.9.2.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0/ports/libxml2/2.9.2... OK
Running patch with /Users/Neophile/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxml2/0001-Revert-Missing-initialization-for-the-catalog-module.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxml2 2.9.2... OK
Running patch with /Users/Neophile/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxml2/0002-Fix-missing-entities-after-CVE-2014-3660-fix.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxml2 2.9.2... OK
Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.9.2... OK
Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.9.2... OK
Running 'install' for libxml2 2.9.2... OK
Activating libxml2 2.9.2 (from /Users/Neophile/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0/libxml2/2.9.2)...
************************************************************************
IMPORTANT NOTICE:

Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxslt-1.1.28
with the following patches applied:
    - 0001-Adding-doc-update-related-to-1.1.28.patch
    - 0002-Fix-a-couple-of-places-where-f-printf-parameters-wer.patch
    - 0003-Initialize-pseudo-random-number-generator-with-curre.patch
    - 0004-EXSLT-function-str-replace-is-broken-as-is.patch
    - 0006-Fix-str-padding-to-work-with-UTF-8-strings.patch
    - 0007-Separate-function-for-predicate-matching-in-patterns.patch
    - 0008-Fix-direct-pattern-matching.patch
    - 0009-Fix-certain-patterns-with-predicates.patch
    - 0010-Fix-handling-of-UTF-8-strings-in-EXSLT-crypto-module.patch
    - 0013-Memory-leak-in-xsltCompileIdKeyPattern-error-path.patch
    - 0014-Fix-for-bug-436589.patch
    - 0015-Fix-mkdir-for-mingw.patch

Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security
updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want
to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and
reinstall nokogiri as follows:

    gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
        [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
        [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

    bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install
************************************************************************
Extracting libxslt-1.1.28.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0/ports/libxslt/1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/Neophile/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0001-Adding-doc-update-related-to-1.1.28.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/Neophile/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0002-Fix-a-couple-of-places-where-f-printf-parameters-wer.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/Neophile/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0003-Initialize-pseudo-random-number-generator-with-curre.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/Neophile/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0004-EXSLT-function-str-replace-is-broken-as-is.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/Neophile/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0006-Fix-str-padding-to-work-with-UTF-8-strings.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/Neophile/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0007-Separate-function-for-predicate-matching-in-patterns.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/Neophile/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0008-Fix-direct-pattern-matching.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/Neophile/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0009-Fix-certain-patterns-with-predicates.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/Neophile/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0010-Fix-handling-of-UTF-8-strings-in-EXSLT-crypto-module.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/Neophile/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0013-Memory-leak-in-xsltCompileIdKeyPattern-error-path.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/Neophile/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0014-Fix-for-bug-436589.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/Neophile/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0015-Fix-mkdir-for-mingw.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running 'configure' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running 'compile' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running 'install' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Activating libxslt 1.1.28 (from /Users/Neophile/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0/libxslt/1.1.28)...
checking for main() in -llzma... yes
checking for xmlParseDoc() in libxml/parser.h... no
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -lxml2... no
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -llibxml2... no
-----
libxml2 is missing.  Please locate mkmf.log to investigate how it is failing.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/Neophile/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --enable-static
    --disable-static
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --enable-cross-build
    --disable-cross-build
    --with-xml2lib
    --without-xml2lib
    --with-libxml2lib
    --without-libxml2lib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Neophile/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/Neophile/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/gem_make.out
```

Comment: I'm guessing that `gem install nokogiri` works ok?

Comment: Correct. In fact, weird thing is... even though I get this error, I just tried to create a site with rails and it created it just fine... >.> So I have no clue why I was getting this error and why it works now...