# libxml2 is missing error

Tags: ruby, libxml2

I am using OSX Yosemite (10.10.3), and when I try to install cupertino via gem using "gem install cupertino" I get the following error.  What can I do to correct this.  I have tried many solutions I have tried online to no avail.

```
libxml2 is missing.  Please locate mkmf.log to investigate how it is failing.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers
```

Comment: What OS do you use? You need to install the appropriate libxml2 development headers package for your system.

Comment: I am using OSX Yosemite (10.10.3)

Comment: Do you use Homebrew? A `brew install libxml2` is maybe sufficient. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24091869/installing-nokogiri-on-osx-10-10-yosemite

Comment: Hi, yes I did that, actually I just solved this after hours of frustration.  So you need to do bre winstall libxml2 as you said.  but my specific problem was Nokogiri.  I had to install it this way NOKOGIRI_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES=1 gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries --with-iconv-dir="$(brew --prefix libiconv)" --with-xml2-config="$(brew --prefix libxml2)/bin/xml2-config" --with-xslt-config="$(brew --prefix libxslt)/bin/xslt-config"

Only after installing Nogogiri this way could I run "gem install cupertino" and have it not error out

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu a `apt-get install libxml2-dev` will install the missing parts.