# Unable to reinstall Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I decided to reinstall Rails on my Mac following the [install Rails Guide](http://installrails.com/steps/install_rails) but it's failing when it tries to `gem install nokogiri`. I'm running Mac OSX version 10.10.5 and have ruby version 2.2.1p85 currently installed.

I get the following errors:

```
Running git apply with /Users/parkour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/patches/libxslt/0017-Updated-config.guess.patch... OK
Running 'configure' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running 'compile' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running 'install' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Activating libxslt 1.1.28 (from /Users/parkour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/ports/x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0/libxslt/1.1.28)...
checking for main() in -llzma... yes
checking for xmlParseDoc() in libxml/parser.h... no
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -lxml2... no
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -llibxml2... no
-----
libxml2 is missing.  Please locate mkmf.log to investigate how it is failing.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

So far I've tried the following commands with no success:

> ```
> brew install libxml2
> ```
>
> (suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31325392/libxml2-is-missing-error))
>
> ```
> xcode-select --install
> gem install nokogiri 
> bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
> bundle install
> ```
>
> (suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25438708/nokogiri-wont-let-me-bundle-install-in-rails))
>
> ```
> brew install libxml2 libxslt libiconv
> NOKOGIRI_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES=1 gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries --with-iconv-dir="$(brew --prefix libiconv)" --with-xml2-config="$(brew --prefix libxml2)/bin/xml2-config" --with-xslt-config="$(brew --prefix libxslt)/bin/xslt-config"
> ```

and

> ```
> ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install nokogiri
> ```
>
> (both suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277456/nokogiri-installation-fails-libxml2-is-missing))

Can anyone provide alternative solutions that might work?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Install brew libs

```
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew install libxml2 libxslt
brew install libiconv
```

then link your new iconv libs:

```
brew link libiconv
```

then install your gem

```
gem install nokogiri -- --with-iconv-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14
```

If it doesn't work then you can try this. I am not sure though but it might work.

```
gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.7.1' -- --use-system-libraries=true --with-xml2-include=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/libxml2
```

Comment: Hi Mohammad, I appreciate the quick response!

This is the output I get when I run your solutions:
>              brew tap homebrew/dupes
'Warning: Tap homebrew/dupes already tapped.'
>              brew install libxml2 libxslt
'Warning: libxml2-2.9.3 already installed'
'Warning: libxslt-1.1.28_1 already installed'
>               brew install libiconv
' homebrew/dupes/libiconv-1.14 already installed'
>              sudo gem update --system

Comment: /specification.rb:17:in `require': cannot load such file -- stringio (LoadError)
 from /Users/parkour/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-
/specification.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
 from /Users/parkour/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-
/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:1291:in `require'
 from /Users/parkour/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:1291:in `<module:Gem>'
 from /Users/parkour/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:116:in `<top (required)>'
 from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require'
 from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'

Comment: then link your new iconv libs:

brew link libiconv
then install your gem

gem install nokogiri -- --with-iconv-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14

Comment: <brew link libiconv --force> created 16 symlinks. However, I still get the previous error even if I run <gem install -v nokogiri 1.6.8rc3>

Answer (score 0):

[Update on 29.03.16]: I couldn't find a solution to resolve this using Terminal/Applications and ended up doing a backup restore. Thankfully, I do weekly Time Machine backups so no real harm done.

Thanks again Mohammad for your quick suggestions.