# invalid gem: package is corrupt -- while installing rails in osx yosemite 10.10.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, nokogiri

I am getting this error while installing rails in osx yosemite 10.10.1

```
 mezbah$ gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc
    ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        invalid gem: package is corrupt, exception while verifying: undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) in /Users/mezbah/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/cache/nokogiri-1.6.6.2.gem
 mezbah$ gem install nokogiri
       ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
            invalid gem: package is corrupt, exception while verifying: undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) in /Users/mezbah/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/cache/nokogiri-1.6.6.2.gem
```

Any Idea??

Comment: Here is a detailed answer how to install nokogiri on osx:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24091869/installing-nokogiri-on-osx-10-10-yosemite

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got my answer. I remove previous cache and then everything fine.

```
sudo rm /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/cache/nokogiri-1.6.6.2.gem

brew install libiconv   

gem install nokogiri
```

Comment: Worked for me!                                                                                       $ sudo rm /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/cache/nokogiri-1.6.6.2.gem                                                                                               $ gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.6.2'