# Rails bundle install not working error with nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I started a new rails project, cd'd inside it and then tried to bundle install

I got the following error

An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.7), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.7'` succeeds before bundling.

I am pretty sure this is a level A problem I tried googling it but found nothing, hope i didnt overlook it

Thanks for any help

edit: if i try to manually install nokogiri it gives the following error

```
Adams-MacBook-Pro:fancy_cars adamkatz$ gem install nokiogiri
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'nokiogiri' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: nokogiri, nokogirl, niceogiri, onigiri
Adams-MacBook-Pro:fancy_cars adamkatz$ gem install nokogiri
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/adamkatz/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20151213-2420-12wvig2.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/adamkatz/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --help
    --clean
/Users/adamkatz/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/adamkatz/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:571:in `block in try_compile'
    from /Users/adamkatz/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:522:in `with_werror'
    from /Users/adamkatz/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:571:in `try_compile'
    from extconf.rb:80:in `nokogiri_try_compile'
    from extconf.rb:87:in `block in add_cflags'
    from /Users/adamkatz/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:619:in `with_cflags'
    from extconf.rb:86:in `add_cflags'
    from extconf.rb:336:in `'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/adamkatz/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/adamkatz/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/nokogiri-1.6.7/gem_make.out
```

Comment: What's the result of trying to gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.7'  manually?

Comment: it gives this error
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'nokiogiri' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: nokogiri, nokogirl, niceogiri, onigiri

Comment: I think you made a spelling mistake when trying to install it manually ;)

Anyway, run it and please update the question with the result

Comment: yes sorry, 
It gave this error when i spell it right

Comment: sorry never posted it as it was too long
ends with exit code 1 not sure what other information you need?

Comment: Edit your question with the result ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the OS X development tools (the output says so, towards the end).

Here are some good instructions on installing xcode: [Installing Ruby on Rails on Mac](https://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html) for Ruby on Rails development (about half way down)

If that works it looks like the simplest way to get you there.

If that doesn't work you might find help here:

1. http://tosbourn.com/nokogiri-wont-install-check-accepted-xcodes-eula/
2. [SO: Installing Nokogiri on OS X 10.10 Yos](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24091869/224334)

Comment: thanks that makes sense i just bought a mac and have been using pc up to this point, :)